# Subsonic 2.2/2.1 bug

Tags: subsonic

This is not a question but a bug in subsonic 2.1/2.2

The method

`public QueryCommand BuildUpdateCommand(Query qry)`

in Dataprovider.cs

generates and invalid Update statement if the Table to be updated is a member of a Schema, i.e. a Schema other than "dbo".

The offending line is

`sql.Append(qry.Provider.DelimitDbName(table.Name));`

The resulting SQL is `"Update <tableName> SET....."`
However the correct SQL should be `"Update <SchemaName>.<tableName>...."`

Commenting out the above line and replacing it with:

`sql.Append(table.QualifiedName);`

generates the correct SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Reporting this to the product's developers may be a better option in getting it solved.

Comment: Well yes, but I don't know where. :). The originals forums on the old subsonicproject website are no longer active and Rob said that it has been shifted to stackoverflow and that he is monitoring this site.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get this issue resolved is to reach out to Rob via the mailing list.  From the Subsonic help page:

> If you have a suggestion or just want to get ahold of the developers - you can use our mailing list which is **subsonicproject@googlegroups.com**. It won't be as fast as StackOverflow and should be used for suggestions or thoughts.